# When we say atom collides with another atom, is it particles collision or wavefunction interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, collision, interactions

I just want to know what is happening in real time when two atoms is setup to collide together, is it really like a billiard where a ball is hitting onto another ball so in this case the two atoms exchanges electromagnetic forces (or nuclear forces) or their wavefunction interacted with each other forming into new wavefunction so that we need detector to observe the byproduct's energy and their position? In short when 2 atoms smashed against each other, is it particles collision, wavefunctions interaction or both depending any observer around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two atoms are described by a single wave-function, which decomposes into a product of one-atom wave functions only long time before and long time after the collision. One can then go to different levels of depth in description: taking into account the atomic structure, the structure of nuclei, the various types of interactions, etc. However, at non-relativistic speeds the collision is dominated by electromagnetic forces.

Hard balls description is really a concept borrowed from classical phsyics, and based on the too obvious analogy with billiard (or other games with balls). One however often characterizes collisions by the [scattering cross-section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(physics)), which is an effetcive parameter based on this analogy (i.e., effective ball cross-section area, if the atoms were balls.).